# How to resolve Depends: libwinpr2-2?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, shared-library

When I want to install any package like gedit:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
apt install gedit
```

Output is:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gedit : Depends: libgspell-1-1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libgtksourceview-3.0-1 (>= 3.21.5) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gir1.2-gtk-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gedit-common (>= 3.22) but it is not going to be installed
```

And when we use:

```
**apt --fix-broken install**
```

We see:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwinpr2-2_2.0.0~git20170725.1.1648deb+dfsg1-7~bpo9+1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwinpr2.so.2.0.0', which is also in package libwinpr2:amd64 2.0.0~git201803141334-0+remmina201803141402.rf8baeb7.d29dd283~ubuntu18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwinpr2-2_2.0.0~git20170725.1.1648deb+dfsg1-7~bpo9+1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Or when I use this command:

```
aptitude install
```

I see this error message:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp2-2:amd64:
 libfreerdp2-2:amd64 depends on libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20161130.1.e60d0d5+dfsg1); however:
  Package libwinpr2-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64:
 libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 depends on libfreerdp2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20161130.1.e60d0d5+dfsg1); however:
  Package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 depends on libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20170725.1.1648deb+dfsg1); however:
  Package libwinpr2-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64:
 remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 depends on libfreerdp-client2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1); however:
  Package libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 depends on libfreerdp2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1); however:
  Package libfreerdp2-2:amd64 is not configured yet.
 remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 depends on libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1); however:
  Package libwinpr2-2:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 **libfreerdp2-2:amd64
 libfreerdp-client2-2:amd64
 remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64**
```

And for example:

```
sudo apt-get install remmina-plugin-rdp
```

Output is:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreerdp-client2-2 : Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20170725.1.1648deb+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
 libfreerdp2-2 : Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20161130.1.e60d0d5+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
 remmina-plugin-rdp : Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try '**apt --fix-broken install**' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

And

```
apt-cache policy
```

Output is:

```
    Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian Backports,a=stretch-backports,n=stretch-backports,l=Debian Backports,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ftp.debian.org
 500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian-Security,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Debian,a=stable-updates,n=stretch-updates,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
 500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
     release v=9.4,o=Debian,a=stable,n=stretch,l=Debian,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.debian.org
Pinned packages:
```

And

```
apt purge libwinpr2
```

Output is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfreerdp-client2-2 : Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20170725.1.1648deb+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
 libfreerdp2-2 : Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20161130.1.e60d0d5+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
 remmina-plugin-rdp : Depends: libwinpr2-2 (>= 2.0.0~git20160317.1.75ae3f5+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with these methods:

```
#Check
dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get remove package*
apt --fix-broken install
#Check again
dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Literally `apt-get remove package*`? Your answer will be much more useful if you give the real commands you used.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the `libwinpr2`, which doesn’t correspond to anything available in Debian 9 (which is what your repositories are set up to track, correctly).

To fix this you need to remove the package, and anything which depends on it:

```
apt purge libwinpr2
```

Hopefully that will work without causing too much havoc, *however*, if `apt` tells you it’s going to delete too many packages, tell it not to (it will ask you), and use `aptitude` instead to install `remmina-plugin-rdp` (or anything else depending on `libwinpr2-2`) at the same time you remove `libwinpr2`:

```
aptitude install remmina-plugin-rdp libwinpr2_
```

(note the underscore at the end, which tells `aptitude` to purge the package).

Comment: I added "purge" result to my question

Comment: Can you try the `aptitude` variant?

Comment: What do you mean? , my Debian version is 9.4

Comment: I mean, in my answer I gave two possible approaches. You tried the `apt purge` one, and that didn’t work; can you try the `aptitude install` one?